# Angular ui grid pagination. How display item count based on filtered items?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, pagination, angular-ui-grid

This is what the pagination currently gives (The total # of items returned by the api): 
[image]

The Problem is I am filtering the data using the columndefs.

```
field: 'claimed', displayName: 'Claimed', width: '8%', visible: true,
filter: {
     term: false,
     type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
     selectOptions: [{value: true, label: true}, {value: false, label: false}]
```

The result of this filter is a limited # of items.  In the current case '3'. 
 I believe the item count is linked to 'grid.options.totalitems'.  
The count is correct when I change data or select a filter.  
It is wrong when the page first loads.
I am using angular ui grid and django to set up my project. I am trying to fix this within my controller that handles the grid setup.
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix that worked for me:
On the $http.get that populates the grid info I had to add:

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.queueGridRefresh();
```

In the controller, here's the code with no errors.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);

        $http.get('/api/this/?format=json')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
                $scope.gridApi.grid.queueGridRefresh();
        });  //Ends http.get


    },
```

And I had to put the http.get inside of the 'onRegisterApi'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the table then you need to write everything of your own.

[Check this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1190/angularjs-powerful-paging-on-table-and-searching-with-delay-and-demo)

Otherwise you can use the `ng-grid` which already have all the features.

Comment: I am using Angular UI-Grid which has functionality built in, like pagination and page count.  It even has the total item count.  I would really like to get Ui-Grid to work as desired rather than write my own table.  Ui-Grid is basically ng-grid 3.